# Return rows if and only if all rows with same name are available during date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table (that I can't change)

| id | name | date | available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Book_1 | 2019-10-11 | Y |
| 2 | Book_1 | 2019-10-12 | Y |
| 3 | Book_1 | 2019-10-13 | Y |
| 4 | Book_1 | 2019-10-14 | Y |
| 5 | Book_2 | 2019-10-11 | Y |
| 6 | Book_2 | 2019-10-12 | Y |
| 7 | Book_2 | 2019-10-13 | Y |
| 8 | Book_3 | 2019-10-11 | Y |
| 9 | Book_3 | 2019-10-12 | N |
| 10 | Book_3 | 2019-10-13 | Y |

User wants to search for books that he/she can borrow from 2019-10-11 to 2019-10-13, and I need to return the following table

| id | name | date | available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Book_1 | 2019-10-11 | Y |
| 2 | Book_1 | 2019-10-12 | Y |
| 3 | Book_1 | 2019-10-13 | Y |
| 5 | Book_2 | 2019-10-11 | Y |
| 6 | Book_2 | 2019-10-12 | Y |
| 7 | Book_2 | 2019-10-13 | Y |

Notice that Book_3 is unavailable on 2019-10-12 so I cant' return it. Is possible with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery with `BOOL_AND` to check that `available` is `true` for all `date`s for a book:

```
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-10-11' AND '2019-10-13'
  AND name IN (
  SELECT name
  FROM books
  WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-10-11' AND '2019-10-13'
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING BOOL_AND(available)  -- or BOOL_AND(available = 'Y') if the column is not a BOOLEAN
);
```

| id | name | date | available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Book_1 | 2019-10-11T00:00:00.000Z | true |
| 2 | Book_1 | 2019-10-12T00:00:00.000Z | true |
| 3 | Book_1 | 2019-10-13T00:00:00.000Z | true |
| 5 | Book_2 | 2019-10-11T00:00:00.000Z | true |
| 6 | Book_2 | 2019-10-12T00:00:00.000Z | true |
| 7 | Book_2 | 2019-10-13T00:00:00.000Z | true |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tc3zpxrGZtVia9Y2AoPVmK/0)

Comment: Great thanks. One more question please, if "available" in the original column isn't boolean value, but rather a number of copies available, so if 0 it means unavailable and above zero is available, how would I do it?

Comment: @Drawio: you can use `HAVING BOOL_AND(available > 0)` to transform the number of copies to a boolean flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the aggregate window function in subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT *,
       MAX(CASE WHEN available = 'N' THEN 1 END) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY name) is_available
 FROM T
) t1
WHERE is_available IS NULL AND 
date BETWEEN '2019-10-11' AND '2019-10-13'
```